# Webscraping script in Python3.4/BeatuifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Wrote code to scrape a website which lists daycares.  Code able to get the relevant information one first of 100+ pages.  No clue how to accommodate code to scrape the site past page 1.  Each page lists only 25 daycares and there are 150+ pages to scrape.  I read something about looking for Post or Get methods that are referenced when clicking on page numbers, but wasn't able to fix my code using that information (believe it was a user named "manhattan" who shared a solution.) Here's a copy of the current code.  Appreciate some help:

---

```
import requests, bs4, re

cc=requests.get('https://data.nj.gov/childcare_results?center=&phone=&capacity_low=&capacity_high=&county=&city=&addr1=&zip=')
cc1=bs4.BeautifulSoup(cc.text,"html.parser")

#Trying to get all instances of <a href ="[website for inspection report for each daycare]> <a>, but line below returns many more instances of href.  Will have to fix that.
#Code below does that for the first page in the above website, but no idea how to make it do the same for the remaining 150+ pages of listings
cc2 = cc1.select('div a')
print(len(cc2))
print (cc2)
```

Comment: To get the inspection reports, use `inspection_reports = [x['href'] for x in soup.find_all('a', href=True, text='Inspection Reports')]`.

Comment: Also, why don't you use the `Download entire Dataset` option? It'll give you all the hrefs in a CSV file. No need to parse all the pages indiviually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the easiest way you can automate the whole process except for downloading the dataset. To get the link you need to take a good look at `xhr` section under `network tab` in dev tools. By changing the last number (`25`) of this URL `https://data.nj.gov/views/INLINE/rows.json?accessType=WEBSITE&method=getByIds&asHashes=true&start=0&length=25` you can get URLs up to the highest number you set. Give this a shot:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = {"columns":[{"id":346250849,"name":"COUNTY","dataTypeName":"text","description":"County that Childcare Center is located in.","fieldName":"county","position":1,"tableColumnId":21926709,"width":86,"format":{},"metadata":{}},{"id":346250850,"name":"CENTER","dataTypeName":"text","description":"Childcare Center name.","fieldName":"center","position":2,"tableColumnId":21926710,"width":342,"format":{},"metadata":{}},{"id":346250851,"name":"PHONE","dataTypeName":"phone","description":"Telephone number of Childcare Center.","fieldName":"phone","position":3,"tableColumnId":21926711,"width":142,"format":{"align":"left"},"metadata":{}},{"id":346250852,"name":"AGES","dataTypeName":"text","description":"Ages of children that Childcare Center provides services to.","fieldName":"ages","position":4,"tableColumnId":21926712,"width":80,"format":{"align":"center"},"metadata":{}},{"id":346250853,"name":"CAPACITY","dataTypeName":"number","description":"Capacity of Childcare Center.","fieldName":"capacity","position":5,"tableColumnId":21926713,"width":80,"format":{"precisionStyle":"standard","noCommas":"false","align":"center"},"metadata":{}},{"id":346250854,"name":"CITY","dataTypeName":"text","description":"City that Childcare Center is located in.","fieldName":"city","position":6,"tableColumnId":21926714,"width":183,"format":{},"metadata":{}},{"id":346250855,"name":"ADDR1","dataTypeName":"text","description":"Street Address of Childcare Center.","fieldName":"addr1","position":7,"tableColumnId":21926715,"width":232,"format":{},"metadata":{}},{"id":346250856,"name":"ADDR2","dataTypeName":"text","description":"Street Address of Childcare Center.","fieldName":"addr2","position":8,"tableColumnId":21926716,"width":241,"format":{},"metadata":{}},{"id":346250857,"name":"ZIP","dataTypeName":"text","description":"Zip code of Childcare Center location.","fieldName":"zip","position":9,"tableColumnId":21926717,"width":73,"format":{"precisionStyle":"standard","noCommas":"false","align":"right"},"metadata":{}},{"id":346250858,"name":"INSPECTIONS","dataTypeName":"dataset_link","description":"Link to webpage with inspection reports for the center","fieldName":"inspections","position":10,"tableColumnId":31789576,"width":100,"format":{},"metadata":{}}],"id":"cru5-4rmm","name":"Licensed Child Care Centers","attribution":"New Jersey Department of Children and Families","category":"Public Safety","description":"Searchable listing of all Licensed Child Care Centers and Inspection Reports.","displayType":"table","hideFromCatalog":False,"hideFromDataJson":False,"iconUrl":"fileId:_Judwh1-EhTD-ocxNjEi_f1JVO4iylkkrFqVjAbCZ6A","publicationAppendEnabled":False,"metadata":{"rdfSubject":"0","attachments":[{"filename":"Licensed_Child_Care_Centers_Explorer_Metadata_Description.docx","assetId":"VDUg-zFJ0y2Fsti8oTr4gkdMiqvg0a2JTk7Co7uxYRg","blobId":"","name":"Licensed_Child_Care_Centers_Explorer_Metadata_Description.docx"}],"custom_fields":{"Asset Details":{"Asset Posting Frequency":"Monthly","Geographic Coverage":"State","Asset Collection Frequency":"Monthly","Asset End Date":"Ongoing","Asset Provider Organization":"Children & Families","Asset Start Date":"1/15/15"},"Common Core":{"Contact Email":"ContactDataNJ@tech.nj.gov","Contact Name":"Data NJ Team","Publisher":"NJ OIT Open Data Center"}},"availableDisplayTypes":["table","fatrow","page"],"rowLabel":"Row","renderTypeConfig":{"visible":{"table":True}},"jsonQuery":{"where":{"operator":"AND","children":[{"operator":"CONTAINS","columnFieldName":"center","value":""},{"operator":"CONTAINS","columnFieldName":"phone","value":""},{"operator":"GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUALS","columnFieldName":"capacity","value":"0"},{"operator":"LESS_THAN_OR_EQUALS","columnFieldName":"capacity","value":"9999999"},{"operator":"CONTAINS","columnFieldName":"county","value":""},{"operator":"CONTAINS","columnFieldName":"city","value":""},{"operator":"CONTAINS","columnFieldName":"addr1","value":""},{"operator":"CONTAINS","columnFieldName":"zip","value":""},{"operator":"CONTAINS","columnFieldName":"zip","value":""}]},"order":[{"columnFieldName":"center","ascending":True}]}},"query":{"filterCondition":{"value":"AND","children":[{"value":"CONTAINS","children":[{"type":"column","columnFieldName":"center"},{"value":"","type":"literal"}],"type":"operator"},{"value":"CONTAINS","children":[{"type":"column","columnFieldName":"phone"},{"value":"","type":"literal"}],"type":"operator"},{"value":"GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUALS","children":[{"type":"column","columnFieldName":"capacity"},{"value":"0","type":"literal"}],"type":"operator"},{"value":"LESS_THAN_OR_EQUALS","children":[{"type":"column","columnFieldName":"capacity"},{"value":"9999999","type":"literal"}],"type":"operator"},{"value":"CONTAINS","children":[{"type":"column","columnFieldName":"county"},{"value":"","type":"literal"}],"type":"operator"},{"value":"CONTAINS","children":[{"type":"column","columnFieldName":"city"},{"value":"","type":"literal"}],"type":"operator"},{"value":"CONTAINS","children":[{"type":"column","columnFieldName":"addr1"},{"value":"","type":"literal"}],"type":"operator"},{"value":"CONTAINS","children":[{"type":"column","columnFieldName":"zip"},{"value":"","type":"literal"}],"type":"operator"},{"value":"CONTAINS","children":[{"type":"column","columnFieldName":"zip"},{"value":"","type":"literal"}],"type":"operator"}],"type":"operator"},"orderBys":[{"expression":{"type":"column","columnId":346250850},"ascending":True}]},"tags":["ool","child care","child care centers","dcf"],"flags":["default","restorable"],"originalViewId":"cru5-4rmm","displayFormat":{}}
res = requests.post("https://data.nj.gov/views/INLINE/rows.json?accessType=WEBSITE&method=getByIds&asHashes=true&start=0&length=25",json=data)
items = res.json()
for item in items:
    links = BeautifulSoup(item['346250858'],"lxml")
    link = links.find("a")['href']
    print(link)
```

Comment: To be clearer: if you set `1000` in place of `25` to the URL then you will get `1000` links.

Comment: Great answer! Learnt something new. But, why are you looping over `find_all("a")`? There's only one `<a>` tag per item. So, won't this `print(links.find("a")['href'])` be enough?

Comment: Thanks.  Why is such an extensive definition of data needed?

Comment: @Keyur Potdar , yep, right you are. There is no need to loop in this case. I wrote this code while doing something else. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @user6860460, without that `data` you won't get any response at all. It's a `post` request and the parameter within `data` is mandatory to pass along with the request. You can find it using dev tools as I've described in the first place.

Comment: @novice-coder, I used your solution above for my script.  But it turns out that the website that hosts the data changed all the ids for its columns in the data file which we hard coded in the script.  Any suggestions on how to find the latest data file for the website I'm trying to scrape?

Comment: @user6860460, see the edit. It is working now. Btw, I should not have edited the code because even if it worked you didn't care to accept it as your answer.

Comment: @novice-coder, thanks.  My apologies - I'm fairly new to stackoverflow and programming in general and am still trying to navigate my way through the protocols on this website.  Anyhow, I found the latest data file and updated it in my script also, but is there a way to upload the latest data file (in case the host of the website changes it again) as opposed to manually updating my script each time it fails because of an outdated data file?  Also, when I run the script with the updated data file, I get an error saying "name 'false' is not defined".  What do you think might be happening here?

Comment: You get `false` is not defined error because the parameter you find in dev tools coming up with lowercase `false` which needs to be fixed manually like `False`. In case of automatic update I don't know any of that sort except for choosing any browser simulator like selenium which is less likely error prone but damn slow. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

As [@KeyurPotdar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7832176/keyur-potdar) mentioned, downloading the csv by clicking `Download entire Dataset` seems like a good option. Once you have the csv, the links can be easily extracted.

```
>>> import csv
... 
... with open('Licensed_Child_Care_Centers.csv', 'r') as f:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(f)
...     links = [row['INSPECTIONS'].split('"')[1] for row in reader]
... 
>>> len(links)
3966
>>> for link in links[-10:]:
...     print(link)
... 
http://www.nj.gov/dcf/families/childcare/centers/15STE0001.shtml
http://www.nj.gov/dcf/families/childcare/centers/170800279.shtml
http://www.nj.gov/dcf/families/childcare/centers/170800294.shtml
http://www.nj.gov/dcf/families/childcare/centers/170800295.shtml
http://www.nj.gov/dcf/families/childcare/centers/170800297.shtml
http://www.nj.gov/dcf/families/childcare/centers/170800298.shtml
http://www.nj.gov/dcf/families/childcare/centers/170300016.shtml
http://www.nj.gov/dcf/families/childcare/centers/10REA0005.shtml
http://www.nj.gov/dcf/families/childcare/centers/170900195.shtml
http://www.nj.gov/dcf/families/childcare/centers/170900180.shtml
```